# Using _.sumBy is possible with a async method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lodash

My question is know is possible sum with lodash (sumBy) values with a async method:

const total = _.sumBy(taxes, t => asyncMethodExample(t.amount));

Comment: `Promise.all(taxes.map(t => asyncMethodExample(t.amount)).then(_.sum).then(console.log, console.error)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use it like that. [_.sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#sumBy) expects the second argument to return the value to be summed, not a Promise.

You can do this:

```
const total = _.sum(await Promise.all(taxes.map(t => asyncMethodExample(t.amount))));
```